# Understanding the meaning of "under which"

Tags: syntax, legalese

What is the meaning of "under which" in this context. What does "which" refer to?

> LESSOR represents and warrants to LESSEE that;
>
> The Deed of Conditional Sale is in force and effect **under which** the
> LESSOR has the right to acquire the rights, title and interest in and
> to the Leased Property from PRA pursuant to the terms of the Deed of
> Conditional Sale.

Does that sentence mean: "The Deed of Conditional Sale is in force and effect. Under this The Deed of Conditional Sale, the LESSOR has the right to acquire the rights ..."? Am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

> The Deed of Conditional Sale is in force and effect **under which** the LESSOR has the right to acquire the rights ...

Yes, your interpretation is right.

The relative pronoun *which* refers to the deed (rather than its closest noun *effect*):

> ... under The Deed of Conditional Sale, the LESSOR has the right to acquire the rights ...